# sed replace a string

Tags: string, bash, sed

I have the following snippet

```
angular.module('workflow-render', ['ng'] ).directive('workflowRender', ['$parse', '$http', '$sce', '$timeout', function ($parse, $http, $sce, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
      retVal : '='
    },
    template: '<div data-ng-if="displayError" style="min-height:150px;"><center><span data-i18n-content="{bundle : \'widgets\', key : \'workflow/Error\'}"></span></center></div>',
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
      $scope.$watch( 'retVal' , function( newVal ) {
        if ( newVal ) {
          Render($scope.retVal);
        }
```

and I want to replace the line

```
template: '<div data-ng-if="displayError" style="min-height:150px;"><center><span data-i18n-content="{bundle : \'widgets\', key : \'workflow/Error\'}"></span></center></div>
```

with

```
template: '<div data-ng-if="displayError" style="min-height:150px;"><center><span style="color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold">Sorry, unable to render workflow due to presence of cyclic workflow transition. We will fix this soon.</span></center></div>
```

I tried suggestions for similar questions but unable to find the way to backquote  the special characters.

Kindly help.  thanks

Comment: I suppose you can at least simplify the string to replace with `center.*`, if there is only one "center" ocurrance.

Comment: Peter, can you please elaborate that ?

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
org=$(cat << 'EOS'
template: '<div data-ng-if="displayError" style="min-height:150px;"><center><span data-i18n-content="{bundle : \'widgets\', key : \'workflow/Error\'}"></span></center></div>'
EOS
)

repl=$(cat << 'EOS'
template: '<div data-ng-if="displayError" style="min-height:150px;"><center><span style="color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold">Sorry, unable to render workflow due to presence of cyclic workflow transition. We will fix this soon.</span></center></div>'
EOS
)

org=$(sed 's#\\#\\\\#g' <<< "$org")
repl=$(sed 's#\\#\\\\#g' <<< "$repl")
sed "s#$org#$repl#" sample.txt
```

Result:

```
angular.module('workflow-render', ['ng'] ).directive('workflowRender', ['$parse', '$http', '$sce', '$timeout', function ($parse, $http, $sce, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
      retVal : '='
    },
    template: '<div data-ng-if="displayError" style="min-height:150px;"><center><span style="color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold">Sorry, unable to render workflow due to presence of cyclic workflow transition. We will fix this soon.</span></center></div>',
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
      $scope.$watch( 'retVal' , function( newVal ) {
        if ( newVal ) {
          Render($scope.retVal);
        }
```

The benefit of this approach is you can write the replacee and the replacer *as is* in the script without modifying the escape sequence by hand.

Comment: can you please explain what the following line actually does?  org=$(sed 's#\\#\\\\#g' <<< "$org")

Comment: To make the explanation easier, please assume the variable `$org` is assigned
to a single backslash \ and you want to replace it with a dash `-`.
In this case `sed '#\#-#'` doesn't work because the single \ is treated
to escape the next character `#`. In order to express a literal backslash,
you need to say `sed '#\\#-#'`. The sentence `org=$(sed 's#\\#\\\\#g' <<< "$org")` does it by *doubling* the number of backslashes.

Comment: The replacement portion also requires the same treatment, although the template
text does not include backslashes.  I've added `repl=$(sed 's#\\#\\\\#g' <<< "$repl")`
sentence in my answer just in case.

Comment: thanks @tshiono. I can understand it *now*. Besides sed, I also understtod the usage of << and <<<

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E -i 's@<span.*</span>@<span style="color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold">Sorry, unable to render workflow due to presence of cyclic workflow transition. We will fix this soon.</span>@g' filename.xml
```

I think this is what you're looking for.
`-E` enables regex and as far as I can tell you want to replace the `<span></span>` part

Answer (score 0):

See `-i s/pattern/replacepattern/g`